# tkz-base errors - file tkz-tools-math.tex not found

Tags: compilation-error, tkz-base

While compiling the file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-base}

\begin{document}

aa

\end{document}
```

I get an error (tkz-base.sty, line 142): "I can't find file `tkz-tools-math.tex'". Trying to fix it, I uninstalled tkz-base and reinstalled it manually from CTAN, and the error was still there. Moreover, I cannot find any file named tkz-tools-math.tex, even in the archive downloaded manually from CTAN. Some comments at the beginning of tkz-base.sty include the list of all files in the tkz-base project and tkz-tools-math.tex is not there. However, line 142 of tkz-base.sty seems to be loading file like that:

```
\usetkztool{base,utilities,math,text,BB,arith,print,misc}
```

Where am I supposed to find this missing file?

Edit: I'm using Miktex 2.9.

Comment: You might want to explain which LaTeX installation you are using? Your MWE compiles just fine for me on TeXLive 2019 frozen.

Comment: tkz-tools-math has been moved from `tkz-base` to `tkz-euclide`. If you are using miktex you should update your package data base in the miktex console. miktex doesn't always pick up such change automatically.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I updated tkz-euclide, it didn't help, but after copying tkz-tools-math.tex from tkz-euclide folder to tkz-base folder compilation was fine. I have no idea why I needed to manually move files, but it works. Thanks for help!

Comment: Don't do this. You are only confusing MiKTeX. Maintain it properly. That means update the package database and the file name data base in user and admin mode in the MiKTeX console.